# Is $C_0^\infty(\Bbb{R}^n)$ a subspace of $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, notation

In the *Navier-Stokes Equations* by Constantin and Foias, there is a proposition says that

> Let $\Omega$ satisfy the segment property. Then $C_0^\infty(\Bbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$, for $1\leq p<\infty$.

$\Omega$ is an open subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$. There is no explanation for the notation $C_0^\infty(\Bbb{R}^n)$ in that old book, which I think means the space of smooth functions with compact support.

The domain of functions in $C_0^\infty(\Bbb{R}^n)$ is $\Bbb{R}^n$. But the domain of functions in $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$ is $\Omega$.

Here is my question:

> In what sense is $C_0^\infty(\Bbb{R}^n)$ a subspace of $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$?

Comment: You have a restriction $\rho \colon C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to C^{\infty}(\Omega)$. The image of that restriction is contained in $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$ and dense in it.

Comment: Is it the same as "$C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ is dense in $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$?"

Comment: No. For nice $\Omega$ and sufficiently large $m$ (can't remember what the bound was, could have been $m > n/2$ or so), functions in $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$ have "well-defined boundary values" in a certain sense. Functions in $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ of course have boundary values $0$, but not all functions in $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$ vanish on the boundary, and the restrictions of $f\in C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to $\Omega$ typically don't. The closure of $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ in $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$ is often denoted by $W^{m,p}_0(\Omega)$. Usually, that's a proper subspace of $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$.

Comment: Ah. Then the restriction $C_0^\infty(\Bbb{R}^n)\to C^\infty(\Omega)$ is also different from the restriction $C^\infty(\Bbb{R}^n)\to C^\infty(\Omega)$?

Comment: The two restrictions have different domains, in that sense they are different, but "in principle" they are the same. On the smaller of the two spaces, they coincide.

Answer (score 1):

I would express the statement as: every function in $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$ can be approximated, in the norm, by functions that are $C^\infty$ smooth on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$, with compact support.

The validity of this statement depends on the geometry of $\Omega$; I don't know what is meant by the segment property but it must be something that enables the extension of Sobolev functions to functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the same Sobolev space (i.e., $\Omega$ is a Sobolev extension domain). Once such an extension is achieved, the extended function can be multiplied by a smooth cut-off to make it compactly supported without changing the values on $\Omega$. Then the standard density result applies.